# Faulted WCF duplex callback after inactivity - keep alive long-running push notifications

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp, duplex

#### In short

How to prevent a duplex callback channel to be closed after an idle period?

#### In detail

I have a mostly working [duplex WCF setup over NetTcpBinding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491844/A-Beginners-Guide-to-Duplex-WCF) i.e. [the client can talk to the server and the server can call back to the client](http://realfiction.net/go/113).

Furthermore, I have [a reliable session such that the client does not lose the connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout.aspx) to the server [after the default period of inactivity](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/pauloreichert/archive/2007/02/22/WCF-Reliable-Sessions-Puzzle.aspx), achieved with [the following configuration on both client and server](http://nogeekhere.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/why-will-wcf-client-be-disconnected.html):

```
var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
// Need to prevent channel being closed after inactivity
// i.e. need to prevent the exception: This channel can no longer be used to send messages as the output session was auto-closed due to a server-initiated shutdown. Either disable auto-close by setting the DispatchRuntime.AutomaticInputSessionShutdown to false, or consider modifying the shutdown protocol with the remote server.
binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
binding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
binding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
```

*However, after a period of inactivity of less than half an hour (haven't measured the minimum time exactly), the server is unable to use the callback again - the server just blocks for a minute or so and I do not see any exceptions, while nothing happens on the client side (no evidence of callback).*

#### Leads and root causes?

Note that I can use the callback fine twice in a row consecutively, as long as I do not wait long in between the callback calls.

- Are the callbacks configured somewhere else? Do callbacks have their own timeouts etc?
- Might it be a blocking/threading issue - [need to either set UseSynchronizationContext=false on your client, or avoid blocking while waiting for the message to be received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273195/wcf-having-trouble-with-one-way-callbacks)
- Should [DispatchRuntime.AutomaticInputSessionShutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.dispatchruntime.automaticinputsessionshutdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) be set to false, and if so, how? I'm not really sure how it relates to reliable sessions and [I do not know where to access this property](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/04/23/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx)
- Anything else?

Comment: A simple approach would be to call a simple `KeepAlive` method (example: every minute) from the client using the same proxy instance, so that it actually never becomes idle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by extending the BaseClient class with an automatic keep alive message to be invoked on the target interface when no other calls are made.

Comment: thanks, will try this unless someone suggests a more preventative measure along the lines of setting inactivity timeouts to gate closing, especially as I need to maintain a number of clients..

Comment: & WCF may provide its own keepalive messaging, but Im not sure what values need to used and if this has changed since 2009?: "According to the documentation a Reliable Session would send a keep-alive message after half of the Inactivity Timeout. Unfortunately the expected behaviour was not the same as the actual behaviour.. the Receive Timeout behaviour overrode the keep-alive behaviour" http://www.smartasses.be/2009/01/26/wcf-reliable-session-and-keep-alives/ And furthermore "increasing timeout will keep connections open for failed clients."?? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10172147/742084